# Create custom reply form in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

i want to change reply form with our custom form field on clicking reply in comment section. By default reply show the same comment form . How I change the reply form . Any Help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Probably, this will facilitate with what you want to achieve:

> Paste the following code into the functions.php file of your WordPress
>   theme, after making the changes described below the code:

```
//change text to leave a reply on comment form
function isa_comment_reform ($arg) {
$arg['title_reply'] = __('Leave a Comment:');
return $arg;
}

add_filter('comment_form_defaults','isa_comment_reform');
```

[Source](https://isabelcastillo.com/change-worpress-leave-a-reply-text)

Hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: this thing change only reply text.

Comment: I want to change the reply form field

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-comments-form-in-wordpress/

Comment: thanks for your response . but by this way the comment form and reply for be the same. I want comment form and reply to comment form be different